# Display/Hide form when radio button selected/Unselected

Tags: javascript, html, forms, radio-button

Could use your help with the following code. (see snipet)
When "Ja" is selected it should display a box to input information.
If "Nein" is selected it should display nothing.
At the moment when I select nein the input box still displays.

**Thanks in advance for your help!**

```js
function myFunction() {

  var radioBoxOne = document.getElementById("nein");
  var radioBox = document.getElementById("ja");
  var text = document.getElementById("Gehalt");

  
  if (radioBox.checked == true){
    text.style.display = "block";
  } 
  
   else if  (radioBoxOne.checked == true){
    text.style.display = "none";
  } 

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <label class="add_top_15">Gehalt (netto)</label>

</br></br>

<div class="form-group radio_input">
    <label for="myCheck" class="container_radio mr-3">Ja
    <input type="radio" name="gehalt" value="ja" class="required" id="ja" onclick="myFunction()">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>

    <label for="myCheckEd" class="container_radio mr-3">Nein
    <input type="radio" name="gehalt" value="nein" class="required" id="nein">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
</div>

</br></br>

<div id="Gehalt" style="display:none" class="form-group add_top_30">
    <label for="Gehalt">Gehalt (netto)</label>
    <input type="text" name="Gehaltt" id="Gehalt" class="form-control required">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the function to Nein radio.

I minified the code a bit.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var radioJa = document.getElementById("ja");
  const text = document.getElementById("Gehalt");
  text.style.display = radioJa.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <label class="add_top_15">Gehalt (netto)</label>

</br></br>

<div class="form-group radio_input">
    <label for="myCheck" class="container_radio mr-3">Ja
    <input type="radio" name="gehalt" value="ja" class="required" id="ja" onclick="myFunction()" />
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>

    <label for="myCheckEd" class="container_radio mr-3">Nein
    <input type="radio" name="gehalt" value="nein" class="required" id="nein" onclick="myFunction()" />
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
</div>

</br></br>

<div id="Gehalt" style="display:none" class="form-group add_top_30">
    <label for="Gehalt">Gehalt (netto)</label>
    <input type="text" name="Gehaltt" id="Gehalt" class="form-control required">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you forgot to make the onclick trigger on your "nein" input

```
<label for="myCheckEd" class="container_radio mr-3">Nein
<input type="radio" name="gehalt" value="nein" class="required" id="nein" onclick="myFunction()">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>

</label>
```

Comment: And this is why `onclick` (and all other non-programatically generated inline event-handlers should no longer be used); please - OP - for your own sake read about [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onchange` event to solve the display issue.

```js
    function myFunction(radio) {
      var text = document.getElementById("Gehalt");

      if (radio.value == "ja"){
        text.style.display = "block";
      } 
      
       else if  (radio.value =="nein"){
        text.style.display = "none";
      } 

    }
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
        <label class="add_top_15">Gehalt (netto)</label>

    </br></br>

    <div class="form-group radio_input">
        <label for="myCheck" class="container_radio mr-3">Ja
        <input type="radio" name="gehalt" value="ja" class="required" id="ja" onchange="myFunction(this)">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>

        <label for="myCheckEd" class="container_radio mr-3">Nein
        <input type="radio" name="gehalt" value="nein" class="required" id="nein" onchange="myFunction(this)">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
    </div>

    </br></br>

    <div id="Gehalt" style="display:none" class="form-group add_top_30">
        <label for="Gehalt">Gehalt (netto)</label>
        <input type="text" name="Gehaltt" id="Gehalt" class="form-control required">
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```